# Hide or Show textbox outside tablix

Tags: ssrs-tablix, rdl

I am facing a critical problem in ssrs reporting. i have a textbox with value and tablix with no record. now i want to hide this textbox when tablix has not no row.here is my report

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-Use RowCount as a additional hidden field in your tablix.
2 Set visibility of the textbox based on the IIF expression which refer to the rowcount from tablix.